# Cannot GET /delete

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, handlebars.js

So I am trying to delete a document on Mongodb but I get the cannot get delete error

### delete route

```js
router.delete("/delete/:id",(req,res)=>{
    filmModel.deleteOne({_id:req.params.id})
    .then(()=>{
        res.redirect("/product-listings");
    })
    .catch(err=>console.log(`Error deleting : ${err}`))
})
```

### Middleware to change to delete method

```
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    if(req.query.method=="PUT"){
        req.method="PUT"
    }
    else if(req.query.method=="DELETE"){
        req.method=="DELETE"
    }
    next();
})
```

### Where the request is called

```
<a href="/delete/{{this._id}}?method=DELETE" class="btn4"><button id="listing-btn" type="button">Delete</button></a>
```

Comment: `<a>` elements may **not** contain `<button>` elements. If you want a link that looks like a button: Apply CSS.

Answer (score 1):

## Had "==" instead of "="

```
else if(req.query.method=="DELETE"){
        req.method=="DELETE"
    }
```

Should've been

```
else if(req.query.method=="DELETE"){
        req.method="DELETE"

    }
```